# Is it possible to change the Terraform Cloud workspace execution mode within the code block instead of in the web interface?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to change the Terraform Cloud workspace to Local execution mode rather than the Remote default?

As the workspace can be created locally, it seems inconvenient to not be able to set options within the code block.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3.6"

  cloud {
    organization = "org"

    workspaces {
      tags = ["foo", "bar"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can in principle create new workspaces from Terraform CLI within an existing configuration, that is limited to the functionality of workspaces that would also be available for folks *not* using Terraform Cloud. Remote operations is a workspace-level setting in Terraform Cloud and so isn't controllable directly from Terraform CLI.

Terraform Cloud's design typically treats workspaces as long-lived objects managed in a central way, rather than as something you would be rapidly creating and destroying directly through CLI commands (even though that is technically possible).

For situations where you want to manage workspaces systematically, I'd recommend instead using a separate management workspace -- that is, a workspace you manually create which is then responsible for declaring all other workspaces -- and use [the `hashicorp/tfe` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe) to pre-declare your workspaces with all of the settings you'd like them to use.

You can set [`execution_mode`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs/resources/workspace#execution_mode) as part of the configuration of a [`tfe_workspace`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs/resources/workspace) resource to select the execution mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23261) in the terraform, but you can do that via curl, as for example:

```
TF_WORKSPACE="something"
MY_ORGANISATION="else"
TF_BACKEND_TOKEN="1234567890"
TF_URL="https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/${MY_ORGANISATION}/workspaces/${TF_WORKSPACE}"
terraform workspace new ${TF_WORKSPACE} && \
curl \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TF_BACKEND_TOKEN}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
    --request PATCH --data \
    '{"data": {"type": "workspaces", "attributes": {"execution-mode": "local"}}}' \
    ${TF_URL}
# ... later
terraform workspace select ${TF_WORKSPACE}
terraform apply -auto-approve
```